# Configure TypeORM default foreign key to follow underscore format instead of camelCase

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Is there a way so all foreign key generated follows **underscore** `user_id` instead of  **camelCase** `userId`.

Is there a way to configure TypeORM so I don't have to think about it when define the relation.

```
  `userId` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible by specifiying `name` property when you define your column like such (see all possible options here https://typeorm.io/#/entities/column-options):

```
@Column('int', { 'name': 'user_id' })
userId: number
```

The database field will then be `user_id` but when accessing the entity it will be mapped back to `userId`